# Multiple whitespaces removed from XML when they should not be

Tags: c++, whitespace, tinyxml

There is a bug in this C++ code. It replaces multiple whitespaces between words by one space.
Can't figure out where it is. It shouldn't trim whitespaces between two words and replace them by one. This is the method which deals with the whitespaces and blanks.

```
const char* TiXmlBase::SkipWhiteSpace( const char* p, TiXmlEncoding encoding )
{
    if ( !p || !*p )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if ( encoding == TIXML_ENCODING_UTF8 )
    {
        while ( *p )
        {
            const unsigned char* pU = (const unsigned char*)p;

            if (    *(pU+0)==TIXML_UTF_LEAD_0
                 && *(pU+1)==TIXML_UTF_LEAD_1 
                 && *(pU+2)==TIXML_UTF_LEAD_2 )
            {
                p += 3;
                continue;
            }
            else if(*(pU+0)==TIXML_UTF_LEAD_0
                 && *(pU+1)==0xbfU
                 && *(pU+2)==0xbeU )
            {
                p += 3;
                continue;
            }
            else if(*(pU+0)==TIXML_UTF_LEAD_0
                 && *(pU+1)==0xbfU
                 && *(pU+2)==0xbfU )
            {
                p += 3;
                continue;
            }

            if ( IsWhiteSpace( *p ) )        // Still using old rules for white space.
                p++;
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while ( *p && IsWhiteSpace( *p ) )
             // while(*p)
            ++p;
    }

    return p;
}
```

**Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<ToDo>
        <bold>Toy                                           store!</bold>
</ToDo>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<ToDo>
        <bold>Toy                                           store!</bold>
</ToDo>
```

**Observed output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<ToDo>
    <bold>Toy store!</bold>
</ToDo>
```

Comment: give input and expected result, pls. Before asking question, use gdb or other hand-write debug methods

Comment: As a programmer, you are in the business of hunting down and slaying bugs. You'd be in the business of finding developer to do that for you were you a manager, or a headhunter.

Comment: This is not your code, I guess. Googling TiXmlBase did the trick. Either read the documentation and/or report the issue upstream...

Comment: Yes. I am trying to fix this issue in TinyXML-1 and struggling a bit in figuring out where the bug lies. So wanted the community's guidance.

Answer (score 5):

Switch to [TinyXML-2](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2docs/index.html):

> Advantages of TinyXML-2
>
> - The focus of all future dev.
> - Many fewer memory allocation (1/10th to 1/100th), uses less memory (about 40% of TinyXML-1), and faster.
> - No STL requirement.
> - More modern C++, including a proper namespace.
> - **Proper and useful handling of whitespace**

#### White Space

> Microsoft has an excellent article on white space: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256097.aspx
>
> TinyXML-2 preserves white space in a (hopefully) sane way that is almost complient with the spec.(TinyXML-1 used a completely outdated model.)
>
> As a first step, all newlines / carriage-returns / line-feeds are normalized to a line-feed character, as required by the XML spec.
>
> White space in text is preserved. For example:
>
> ```
> <element> Hello,  World</element>
> ```
>
> The leading space before the "Hello" and the double space after the comma are preserved. Line-feeds are preserved, as in this example:
>
> ```
> <element> Hello again,  
>           World</element>
> ```
>
> However, white space between elements is not preserved. Although not strictly compliant, tracking and reporting inter-element space is awkward, and not normally valuable. TinyXML-2 sees these as the same XML:
>
> ```
> <document>
> <data>1</data>
> <data>2</data>
> <data>3</data>
> </document>
>
> <document><data>1</data><data>2</data><data>3</data></document>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `bool TiXmlBase::condenseWhiteSpace` to `false` in the file `tinyxml.cpp`, or calling [`TiXmlBase::SetCondenseWhiteSpace(false)`](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlBase.html#0f799ec645bfb8d8a969e83478f379c1) in runtime. The first worked for me.

This probably didn't exist in 2012, but it exists now.